# Can't access order page for my online shop from the cart page-django url error

Tags: python, django

Am doing online shop example in Django 2.0.5 and i have run into url error when trying to checkout the cart to the order page.it brings the error below

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/%25%20url
Using the URLconf defined in myshop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
orders/
cart/ [name='cart_detail']
cart/ add/<int:product_id>/ [name='cart_add']
cart/ remove/<int:product_id>/ [name='cart_remove']
[name='product_list']
<slug:category_slug>/ [name='product_list_by_category']
<int:id>/<slug:slug>/ [name='product_detail']
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
```

The current path, cart/% url, didn't match any of these.

myshop/orders/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'orders'
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', views.order_create, name='order_create'),
]
```

myshop/orders/views.py

```
from .models import Order
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,
                                         product=item['product'],
                                         price=item['price'],
                                         quantity=item['quantity'])
            # clear the cart
            cart.clear()
            return render(request,
                          'orders/order/created.html',
                          {'order': order})
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
    return render(request,
                  'orders/order/create.html',
                  {'cart': cart, 'form': form})
```

myshop/orders/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Order, OrderItem
class OrderItemInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = OrderItem
    raw_id_fields = ['product']
@admin.register(Order)
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
                    'address', 'postal_code', 'city', 'paid',
                    'created', 'updated']
    list_filter = ['paid', 'created', 'updated']
    inlines = [OrderItemInline]
```

myshop/cart/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'cart'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    path('add/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_add, name='cart_add'),
    path('remove/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_remove, name='cart_remove'),  
]
```

myshop/myshop/urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('orders/', include('orders.urls', namespace='orders')),
    path('cart/', include('cart.urls', namespace='cart')),
    path('', include('shop.urls', namespace='shop')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

myshop/cart/templates/cart/detail.html

```
</table>
 <p class="text-right">
  <a href="{% url "shop:product_list" %}" class="buttonlight">Continue 
shopping</a>
 <a href="% url "orders:order_create" %}" class="button">Checkout</a>
 </p>
{% endblock %}
```

am doing the book django 2 by example,please help.am stuck

Comment: You're missing the opening `{` in the second URL tag.

Comment: thank you,it worked, clearly i couldn't see such a small mistake....

Answer (score 0):

## Try it

Hi,
Error in detail.html:

```
href="{% url "shop:product_list" %}"
```

use single or double quote if use outer double then use inside single quote and then no error should display:
try it:

```
href="{% url 'shop:product_list' %}"
```